# Does having the name of a country in the site title hurt SEO for other countries?

Tags: seo, keywords, title, local-seo

Let's say the website title has the word "Australia" in it. However, the target audience for the website is not just Australia, in particular I wish to target US/UK.

1) Does it negatively impact SEO ranking for US/UK search engines, if there is the word "Australia" in my site title? Changing the site title is very easy, and I would do that if there is a negative impact.

The converse question is:

2) Does having the word "Australia" positively impact SEO ranking for Australian search engines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having any word, be it of a country or anything in the title, will positively impact the SEO ranking of your website for that term/word.

The title is very important for higher SEO ranking and therefore should be wisely created/chosen and used.
**Reasons:**

1) It gives a good indication to a crawler (Search Engine like Google) about the content of page/site       
 2) It showcases in a rich snippet of search       results and serves as the entry point for your user. If the content is    relevant, the chances of a user clicking your results are higher.

So, if you think that putting Australia in the title would help user reach your site or improves the search result rich snippet in any way, shape or form, then go ahead and use it. Otherwise please ignore and use more relevant words/terms.

While putting a word like Australia or any other country name for that matter may not hurt your SEO ranking, as i already explained, when a user sees Australia, he/she might get a negative impact if user is not from Australia.

Comment: I guess this will hurt my sire quite bad then foreverhuman.co.za but it's all about my cats, but it doesn't reference cats in the domain or title is that a bad thing?

Comment: If it is all about cats and you have not mentioned it anywhere in title or description or in content then on what keywords you expect Google to rank your pages. Also not adding something does not hurt whatever is added. Adding something might positively impact the keywords related to that.

Comment: I don't know actually, I just thought it's a good website content wise and people will pick it up. Cats and kittens gets referenced in the blog posts but not on the landing page so much. I actually don't know what the hell to do with that main index page.

Comment: Use these for strong interlinking as the product pages gets a huge boost on how their product listing page ranks. You can add these strong product links on product listing as well as target major driving keywords there.